# Should I use a second router in extended mode or in normal route mode?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I have a good router (default Cisco from ISP) but with terrible Wi-Fi (no external antenna, and no `ac` just `a/b/g/n`).

So I bought a good Wi-Fi router (TP-Link Archer C7, which is enough for my Wi-Fi needs). But I've been using it as a router/DHCP server too. The main reason is that it came configured like that and the web interface is not the best, so I kept thinking if it worth it.

Should I keep like that or should I use it in extended mode? *They are connected by ethernet cable.*

My worries are if I'm double routing/DHCP'ing.

**Solution:**

Put first router in bridge mode and use the second one (good router) in normal mode (routing, Wifi, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and likely the fastest setup here would be to bridge your Cisco and allow the C7 to perform all network functions and provide your wireless access. Assuming they are physically in the same location (not one in the basement and one in the attic).

If they are separate, use AP mode on the C7 or manually configure it as an AP if it doesnt have such an option.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. They are in the same location. I only want to use the Wifi from the second device as this second device covers the whole house where the first one fails.
But I need the first one because it's also a cable modem (besides being a Wifi routes).

Do you think it's ok to use like that? The connection seems pretty good and not affected by the "double" routing.

Comment: If you enable bridge mode the cable modem stops being a router and becomes just a dumb modem. I have a similar setup (Are you with a cable provider in europe perhaps?) and there is a significant improvement in latency by using a decent router vs the ISPs one for routing.

Comment: Is there a way to disable routing in the first one (cable modem) instead of disabling in the second one (good router)?

Comment: Thats what Im suggesting, set the cisco to bridge mode.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Will it keep my access to my ISP and other config?

Comment: Also, how would I access it's interface once it's IP is gone?

Comment: Yes,, itll stay live. IP normally would be 192.168.100.1

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I did it and it seems to work fine. Old ip `192.168.0.1` is gone and replaced with `192.168.100.1`.

Answer (score 1):

The basic steps to use a WiFi router as an access point are always the same:

1. Disable DHCP
2. Make sure the new router’s IP address doesn’t conflict with anything on your existing network, yet is in the same subnet, so you can access its web interface
3. Set your wireless configuration to be identical to the network you’re trying to extend/replace
4. Connect the new router to your existing wired network using a LAN port (important) on the new router

That way, there’s no double NAT and no DHCP conflicts. The new router will just provide wireless access to your wired network.

Comment: They are in the same location.
I have connected the LAN port (1st) with the WAN port (2nd). 
It seems to be working fine, but both are routing. So you are saying it would be better to let the first routing and the second one only with the Wifi?

Comment: Yes. If you’re satisfied with your current router’s performance. If not, refer to Linef4ault’s answer. Double NAT is not desirable.